# Does GLSL have a built in bilinear interpolation function?

Tags: function, opengl, glsl, interpolation

This is what I am doing now. Is there a `built-in` function that does this? The documentation is cumbersome and I haven't found something like that.

```
vec4 biLerp(vec4 a, vec4 b, vec4 c, vec4 d, float s, float t)
{
  vec4 x = mix(a, b, t);
  vec4 y = mix(c, d, t);
  return mix(x, y, s);
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no built-in GLSL function to perform 2D linear interpolation on values. You have to write it yourself.